# How to add thumbnail to the end of embedded video?

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, thumbnails

I have an embedded video on my site and am currently using the following code. I don't want the video to loop but it gives a black screen once the video is done playing. I know there is the `poster` option under the `video` tag but it only displays the thumbnail at the start of the video and not after it has finished playing.

Could you all help me out as to how should I add the thumbnail after the video is done playing?

```
<video controls autoplay poster="some_path">
    <source src="some_video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two ways to solve your issue.

This one will set your current frame to position 0 (the very first frame) after the video will end. You can set any frame you like. This solution is recommended.

```
<video controls id="myVideo" poster="test.jpg">
  <source src="test.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
<script>
let myVideo = document.getElementById("myVideo");
myVideo.onended = function() {
  myVideo.currentTime = 0;
};
</script>
```

The next one will reload the video source, so the poster will appear again. According to specification of `poster` in `video` it will be displayed only until the video starts once. After that, the only way to get the poster again - reload the video `src`, and a `poster`, just to make sure. Will work a little bit more stable.

```
<video controls id="myVideo" poster="test.jpg">
  <source src="test.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
<script>
let myVideo = document.getElementById("myVideo");
myVideo.onended = function() {
  myVideo.poster = "test.jpg"
  myVideo.src = "test.mp4"
};
</script>
```